# how to switch to different javascript context in chrome console

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, contextmenu

Below is the ss of context:

[image]

Currently it is in top, how can I switch to my_frame using javascript in console itself?

Comment: You mean from the keyboard instead of using the menu?

Comment: @Barmar using javscript / jquery code

Comment: AFAIK you can't manipulate the console in JS.